# (AngularJS) how to loop through an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

That is an array on php.i have transformed it in json (with json_encode)

```
Array
(
    [codehttp] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 200
            [3] => 200
        )

    [time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2014-09-15 13:54:04
            [1] => 2014-09-15 13:54:04
            [2] => 2014-09-15 13:54:04
            [3] => 2014-09-15 13:54:04
        )

    [channel] => Array
        (
            [0] => channel1
            [1] => channel1
            [2] => channel1
            [3] => channel1
            [4] => channel1
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => android
            [1] => android
            [2] => android
            [3] => android
            [4] => android
        )

    [indice] => Array
        (
            [0] => masterplaylist
            [1] => video_110000
            [2] => video_190000
            [3] => video_300000
            [4] => video_500000
        )

    [cdn] => Array
        (
            [0] => cdn1
            [1] => cdn1
            [2] => cdn1
            [3] => cdn1
            [4] => cdn1
        )

)
```

Please I would like to know how to parse (the codehttp field) in javascript the final json variable. I would like to do it into an angularjs controller.

I have tried this code (in a controller) but it does'nt work

```
$scope.flag_a = 'good';

for(var key in $scope.content.codehttp)
{
        if($scope.content.codehttp[key] != '200')
        {
                $scope.flag_a = 'bad';
        }
}
```

Comment: `for...in` loops are meant for objects, not for arrays, use `for(i=0;i<$scope.content.codehttp.length;++i)` for an array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At first you need to make sure, your response actually is treated as JSON (thus results in a proper javascript object), and then you can use on of the following three ways:

Using angularjs's own method [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

```
$scope.content = {};
$scope.content.codehttp = [200, 200, 200, 201];

angular.forEach($scope.content.codehttp, function(value, key) {
  if (value != 200) {
    $scope.flag_a = 'bad';
  }
})
```

Using a plain ['for'](http://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/for) loop:

```
for(i=0;i<$scope.content.codehttp.length;i++) { 
  if ($scope.content.codehttp[i] != 200) {
    $scope.flag_a = 'bad';
  }
}
```

Using the (relatively new) native [Array.prototype.forEach](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/javascript/Array/forEach) method:

```js
$scope = {};
$scope.content = {};
$scope.content.codehttp = [200, 200, 200, 201];

$scope.content.codehttp.forEach(function(value, key) {
    if (value != 200) {
        // for demonstrational purposes only:
        document.write("Entry #"+(key+1)+" contained a bad status: "+value);
        $scope.flag_a = 'bad';
    }
})
```

Comment: missing `Array.prototype.forEach`

Comment: Nice addition, minus the alert()

Comment: changed the alert to a similarly ugly `document.write` to give some feedback of the working code. (Sry for editing this so much, just wanted to try out the new code snippet functionality:-D)